# find object real name by guid?

Tags: windows, windows-7, device

i am using windows7, and i saw many **3ab22e31-8264-4b4e-9af5-a8d2d8e33e62**[1] &[25] in many of my device list's properties, is there way to find object name by GUID ?

what is **{3ab22e31-8264-4b4e-9af5-a8d2d8e33e62}**[1] &[25] refers to ?

thanks

Comment: The point of GUID/UUID identifiers is to avoid requiring a central authority. So what you're asking for seems like it would be both pointless and difficult to track. See [RFC 4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt). See also [Registry Trees for Devices and Drivers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549538%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), since you may be referring to a device class GUID as can be found in `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceClasses`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Practically speaking, google it.

GUID's are used in thousands of contexts, and often there's not even a concept of a name. For instance, GUIDs are commonly used in databases to uniquely identify each row in a table. The table may have a name, but the row doesn't. But how would you even know which database to search? A GUID is effectively just a 128 bits number, almost without any indication where it came from (some can be traced by to your computer, but that's about it).